Images under homotopies from 0 to the identity
My question is the following. Given a chain complex, if we find a chain homotopy between the identity and the zero map, the chain complex is exact. The bar construction is one of these instances (I don't want to bother you with the details here). Now this implies that, if the homotopies are really morphisms in the category, that we in fact have that the image of any additive functor of this sequence is exact. In the case of the bar construction this is obviously wrong. Can you maybe pinpoint where exactly this goes wrong? I think it might be that the homotopies are only Z-linear and not ZG-linear. Thanks so much and sorry for the long question, but I think formulas would not help here.

Re “if the homotopies are really morphisms in the category”: what category do you mean?

Sorry for the confusion. So what I mean by that is the following. Sometimes, for example in case of the bar construction, you don't need the chain homotopy to be ZG-linear to imply that the sequence is exact. So the chain homotopy is not a morphism in the category of ZG-modules.
